# Grabbing images from a Website

Tags: php

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction.

I have a rather large spreadsheet of product info that needs plugging into a shop. The tricky bit is that the spreadsheet has a link which points to the relevant page on another site which has the products details, and what i need to do is grab that relevant Image and save locally, so I can use later.The reason Why Im thinking down this line is there are 7500 products....

My friend suggested I could maybe use php & filepopen.

The image does have an outer tag ID which I can refer to.

I was thinking of iterating through the spreadsheet this is the type of link I have to work with

http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=APCRBC105

the images themselves are called something random, but I figured I could rename them as I grab them to the more relevant SKU number.

- so iterate through the spreadsheet by SKU number
- identify the image by the relevant id on the page (I'm assumming it's
  in the same place     on every page)
- save the image while renaming to the correct SKU number

Any ideas on how I could go about this ? the thought of visiting each page manually and saving the image 7500 times doesn't seem the best way forward!

Thanks for looking

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: Actually, I don't see any other way forward than what you outlined.

Comment: But you should be using the larger images at http://www.apc.com/products/moreimages.cfm?partnum=APCRBC105

Comment: yeah actually I could do with those larger images, good point!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rip the base_sku from your links.

APCRBC105

Then use curl to fetch the image page

http://www.apc.com/products/moreimages.cfm?partnum=APCRBC105

Rip the image link with a regex epression on :

```
    <div align="center">
<img align="center" src="http://www.apcmedia.com/resource/images/500/Front_Left/35531838-5056-9170-D33F24AE47742E6C_pr.jpg" />
</div>
```

Then use curl again to rip the actual image and save it.
That should work..

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any issues regarding copyrighted material, take a look at Google Refine.

You can grab content from websites based on your cell values and use them afterwards to build more complex scenarios. 
See the [screencasts](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/Screencasts) for more info (screencast 3 talks about fetching values via URLs).

Once you have the Image URL's in your spreadsheet, it should be fairly easy to fetch them via curl or similar.

Comment: Hi, It's basically a spreadsheet of the products, and the links are off their suppliers website - so this is all good, thanks I will take a lok google refine.